# Why does certbot (letsencrypt) recieve a 403 forbidden?

Tags: nginx, letsencrypt, certbot

Trying to create certificates for my domain on a nginx webserver. When certbot is ran it gives me a 403 unauthorized error since it cannot see the file on the domain for some reason, but if I replicate the file I am able to view it from my domain.

Command being ran

```
certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/html/example.com/website/ -d www.example.com -d example.com
```

The error received

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for www.example.com
http-01 challenge for example.com
Using the webroot path /var/www/html/example/website for all unmatched domains.
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. www.example.com (http-01): urn:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/lBNrwYPRz_0iFkXPGG2jfixRecA7VMMDOmYst_qzXCI: "<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>"
```

I do understand that NGINX needs location blocks for some things, but if I re-create these files I can access them. (It downloads the file automatically?)

> www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/lBNrwYPRz_0iFkXPGG2jfixRecA7VMMDOmYst_qzXCI

Here is my basic NGINX configuration.

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name www.example.com example.com 167.0.0.0;
    root /var/www/html/example/website;
    index index.html index.php index;

    location /forums {
        root /var/www/html/example;
    }


}
```

Comment: can you please provide the corresponding lines from file: `/var/log/nginx/error.log` (redact sensitive info if necessary)

Comment: also, what if you use `--webroot-path` instead of `-w` maybe? also certbot doesnt have the slash on the end of the webroot path - just like you cant have the slash in nginx so do ` --webroot-path /var/www/html/example.com/website`

Comment: thanks. removing the slash at the end of the directory with -w worked. dont know why since the docs show a / at the end. https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#certbot-commands you can post the answer